# python: why do I need to assign a generator function to a variable or it won't work?

Tags: python, generator

Why does this work:

```
def even_gen():
    n = 0
    while True:
        yield n
        n += 2

evens_ = even_gen()
evens = list(next(evens_) for _ in range(5))

#[0,2,4,6,8]
```

But this doesn't:

```
def even_gen():
    n = 0
    while True:
        yield n
        n += 2

evens = list(next(evens_gen()) for _ in range(5))

#[0,0,0,0,0]
```

The only difference is moving the generator inside the list function. I find it super peculiar that we need to first assign it to a variable, and then it works...

What's the reason?

Answer (score 6):

Because `evens_gen()` creates a new generator in every iteration hence `next` will always get the first element which is `0`.